# Something like Controls("lbl" & i) for PowerPacks RectangleShape?

Tags: vb.net

I am doing something for my VB.NET class in high school and I previously found on the internet a way to use `Controls("lbl" & i).Text = "Example"` to quickly change/set multiple labels.

Now we are doing somewhat simple animations (I like to take it a step further) and I want to have a timer that makes it so every rectangle that gets created with a key press starts moving through a timer. If that's confusing basically what I want to do is (incorrect syntax of course because I'm using controls() as my example):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

For i = 0 to createdRectangleAmount
    Controls("rec" & i).left += 1
Next

End Sub
```

Also as one last side note, the timer only gets enabled AFTER a rectangle as been created (rectangle 0), so this wouldn't produce errors, outside of the obvious misuse of Controls()

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, sorry, somehow forgot question mark. Looking for something like Controls() that can be used for the PowerPacks RectangleShape to loop through every rectangle on a form and move them all by 1 to the right edge of the screen in a timer. Well, not all, but simply the ones named "rec" + a number starting at 0

Answer (score 0):

Get a specific control collection with filter. `OfType` asks for what control type you are looking for. The `Where` predicate does some filtering with condition expression as below). This also assumes that all controls are located in the forms control collection and not in any other container(panel, groupbox, etc...). As always check your [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.simpleshape.bounds.aspx)

```
Dim recs = Me.Controls.OfType(Of RectangleShape)().
              Where(Function(r) r.Name.StartsWith("rec"))

For Each rec In recs
 rec.SetBounds(recBounds.Left + 1, rec.Bounds.Top, rec.Width, rec.Height)
Next
```

Comment: What must I import to use `Where` ?

Comment: I believe it is `System.LINQ`

Comment: Nevermind that your formatting got messed up and all I had to do was backspace the Where to the . Now what would I put in the `For Each` to move them to the left += 1? Sorry I'm very new tot he programming scene with this type of stuff.

Comment: Should be on one line - I adjust it to fit the code window.

Comment: Alright I got that but now what do I put in the `For each rec In recs` statement to move them to the left += 1?

Comment: most languages support multi-line statements - this wont produce any errors under many circumstances, all is well.

Comment: See above update. I don't use these controls, but it looks like you access the `Left` property thru the `Bounds` property.

Comment: Okay bear with me haha. This new code produces the error 'Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment'

Comment: Also, just to let you in on what I've done, I had to change your `RectangleShape` to `PowerPacks.RectangleShape` and also when inspecting the `recs` variable it shows that it yields 0 results, despite having a rectangle on the form named `rec0`

Comment: And it is added to `Me.Controls` and not any other container?

Comment: Yep. Even tried doing it without the search for name and it still says it can't find any rectangles

Comment: Not sure what to tell you - I have used this before. Double check some things it should work.